# How to implement read-only ContentProvider?

Tags: android, permissions, android-contentprovider, readonly, android-contentresolver

I am wondering how to best implement a read-only ContentProvider.
I want my data source to be modified only from within my own application through additional special methods of my ContentProvider (which of course are not accessible through a ContentResolver).
In other words, other applications should only be able to use my ContentProvider's query method but not insert, delete, or update.

The obvious solution seems to be to just return null/0/0 and do nothing else in insert/delete/update. Would it be better to always throw an Exception in these methods instead so as to communicate clearly that these operations are not allowed? Or is there even a possibility of restricting the access to the ContentProvider to the query method only via permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method to accomplish this is via security permissions which you can access at [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#manifest) in the ContentProvider paragraph. Specifically, you would set a [writePermission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#writePermission) on your provider in your AndroidManifest xml file.

If you do not wish to use security permissions, however, you can use the approaches mentioned in your second paragraph. I would suggest throwing exceptions so that it is clear that those particular insert/update/delete features can't be accessed.

Comment: Also: If you need access to the ContentProvider instance within Activities in your app - **first** get a ContentProviderClient for your ContentProviders authority - **then** use ContentProviderClient#getLocalContentProvider() - and **finally** cast that to your implementation - and presto - access to the ContentProvider instance used by external clients.

Comment: Thanks! But if I list a certain permission in the writePermission attribute of my provider and an application lists the same permission in its uses-permissions, won't it still be able to access these methods?

Comment: No, getLocalContentProvider only works locally (i.e. within the same app) - so they can't access them. writePermission will allow them to use insert/update and delete on your provider - according to the URI scheme you configure of course.

Comment: As far as I am aware, if other applications list the permission you have listed in writePermission, they could gain access to those methods. Like you said, however, the user has to grant them and the developer needs to know the permission string. Of course, none of that matters if your CP methods only throws exceptions.

Comment: @Jens: I meant that other applications could access insert/delete/update if they have the corresponding permissions, not my custom methods. Either way, I did it now by throwing OperationNotSupportedExceptions in insert/delete/update and I use my custom methods to modify the data. Thank you for explaining how to obtain a ContentProvicer instance. I think it would have taken me a lot of time to figure that out and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 4):

Two years later, I'm asking myself the very same question.
I understand that permissions are the answer.

Nevertheless, you have to write something inside the "insert/delete/update" methods (that hopefully will not be callable).

I would agree on using an exception because, as it is not supposed to be call, you must be warned if it is.

But a line found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html) says:

> Although you must implement these methods, your code does not have to
>   do anything except return the expected data type. For example, you may
>   want to prevent other applications from inserting data into some
>   tables. To do this, you can ignore the call to insert() and return 0.

That would say the good way to do is just to return null/0/0. I'm gonna use this way.