# Secure Content Provider

Tags: android, security, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

Is is possible to make content provider read-only? I know that this question was asked few times but according to all of them (eg. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9085951/3279023)) I have to write my own custom write permission.

```
<permission android:name="com.test.WRITE_DATABASE" android:protectionLevel="normal" />
<permission android:name="com.test.READ_DATABASE" android:protectionLevel="normal" />


//...

  <provider
     android:authorities="xxx"
     android:name="xxx"
     android:exported="true"
     android:readPermission="com.test.READ_DATABASE"
     android:writePermission="com.test.WRITE_DATABASE" />
```

But hacker could decompile my app and look inside manifest file and then he can easily write his own app with:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.test.WRITE_DATABASE" />
```

So it's almost useless... 
I have several apps to use one Content Provider inside my **main** application. Only this application should have write permission - other should only read from this database. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See documentation about permissions here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html

Answer to your question is a `android:protectionLevel` property of a permission. You can set it to `signature` so only applications that signed with same key will be able to request this permissions.

Comment: Any suggestion if we want to expose the data to other application (with different signature) how we can maintain security